# Is the MemSQL reported version 5.5.8 adjustable?

Tags: security, singlestore

In [MemSQL documentation FAQ page][1]

[1]: https://docs.memsql.com/v7.0/introduction/faqs/memsql-faq/, it says:

> MemSQL reports the version engine variable as 5.5.8. Client drivers look for this version to determine how to interact with the server.

This is understandable, but an unfortunate side effect of this is MemSQL fails the security scan tests by security team and brings up a lots of red flags. In the same page, MemSQL says MemSQL is not necessary impacted by any of MySQL found security vulnerabilities:

> The MemSQL and MySQL servers are separate database engines which do not share any code, so security issues in the MySQL server are not applicable to MemSQL.

But red flags are red flags, so I wonder if this reported version is user adjustable so that we can calm the security scan test? But also want to know what are known impacts that could be caused by changes of the reported version of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the "Mysql compatibility" version can be changed via the `compat_version` global variable.  You should set it to the version string you want returned via select @@version (i.e., '8.0.20').  Keep in mind now and then client drivers and mysql applications check this version to enable\disable features so you need to test out the impact of the change on your applications.

Comment: I try your solution but it fails: `mysql> set global compat_version='8.0.20';
ERROR 1231 (42000): Variable 'compat_version' can't be set to the value of '8.0.20'`

Comment: Setting to `5.7.20` works. So I believe `compat_version` is dependent. Mine is `6.7`, I guess `8.0.20` probably works on MemSQL version 7 and later. With this variable is set, the latter connections can see the new version. Thanks for the quick solution.